# Open ionic modal from ionic popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I call `openAddCardModal()` in `ModalController` from `PopupController`?

```
function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state) {
   $scope.showPaymentOptionsPopup = function() {
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Payment Options',
            cssClass: 'popup-vertical-buttons',
            buttons:[    
            {
                text: "Add",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                    // call openAddCardModal();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Edit",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Close",
                type: 'button-dark',
                onTap: function(){
                }
            }
            ]
        });
    }; 
}

function ModalController($scope, $ionicModal, $stateParams) {
    // addCardModal() 

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/payment-add-card.view.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.addCardModal = modal;
    })

    $scope.openAddCardModal = function() {
        $scope.addCardModal.show()
    }

    $scope.closeAddCardModal = function() {
        $scope.addCardModal.hide();
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.addCardModal.remove();
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between PopupController and ModalController?

Comment: `showEditImagePopup()` is called in the view with `<a class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="showPaymentOptionsPopup()" ng-controller="PopupController">`. It is a popup ( http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/). I want to call a modal (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) from the popup when the user clicks on the Edit button. Image for clarity: http://imgur.com/m6vId0d

Comment: @dfsq no other relation comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AngularJS **Service** to set communiaction between controllers

Read this: [Communicate with controllers in angular js](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html)

Your service can look like this:

```
function ServiceName(){
    var serviceFunction;

    return {
        set: function(funcFromCtrl){
            serviceFunction = funcFromCtrl;
        },
        call: function(){
            serviceFunction();
        }
    }
})
```

And Controllers:

```
function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state, ServiceName) {
    ...
        onTap: function(){
            ServiceName.call();
        }
    ...
}

function ModalController($scope, $ionicModal, $stateParams, ServiceName) {
   ...
       ServiceName.set($scope.openAddCardModal);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and keep getting the following error: http://imgur.com/PYVQMLG. My code is here: http://pastebin.com/WAECu4r2. Line 113 is `call: function(){
                serviceFunction();
            }`

Comment: You haven't injected your service to controllers dependencies: 

`function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state, ModalPopupCommunicationService ) { ......}`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add those to the pastebin. I have already done that - `function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state, ModalPopupCommunicationService)` and `function ModalController($scope, $ionicModal, $stateParams, ModalPopupCommunicationService)`. Their inclusion doesn't take away the error message.

Comment: Oh I missed a comma after set function in the service

Comment: Thanks. The error message is gone but now whenever I click on the "Add" button, I get a `serviceFunction is not a function` error at `call: function(){
                serviceFunction();
            }`

Comment: You should change places of `ModalPopupCommunicationService.set($scope.openAddCardModal);` and `$scope.openAddCardModal = function ...` 
First you should define that `$scope.openAddCardModal` is a function that does something, and after that set it to service.

Comment: Great that fixed it. Working great now!